# webpack 2 babel presets Пытается искать модуль es2015 в той же директории что и файл

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babel

Структура папок:

```
/dev_tools/
/dev_tools/webpack.config.js
/dev_tools/node_modules/
/dev_tools/package.json

/www/
/www_dev/
```

Конфигурация webpack 2 :

```
module.exports = {
    context: __dirname,
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.scss', '.less', '.node'],
        modules: [
            path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
            path.resolve(__dirname, '../www_dev/js/components')
        ]
    },
    entry: {
        liveWiew: path.resolve(__dirname, '../www_dev/js/entries/liveWiew.jsx')
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../www/js/entry_output'),
        filename: "[name].entry.js"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "babel-loader",
                        query: {
                            presets: [["es2015", {"modules": false}], 'react']
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

В resolve.modules указана папка node_modules  и модули от туда успешно подгружаются.

НО почему то babel-loader пытается найти es2015 в директории, где находится компилируемый файл. И Так со всеми файлами

При компиляции выходит ошибка:

```
Module build failed: Error: Couldn't find preset "es2015" relative to directory "C:\\work\\projects\\app\\www_dev\\js\\entries"
```

В чем проблема?
Почему остальные модули успешно подгружаются через inmort из папки указанной в modules, а именно лоадер не хочет.

Мои установленные модули

```
{
  "name": "dev",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.23.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.3.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.23.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обновил wevpack.config.js.
А именно массив presents

```
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.jsx$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    query: {
                        presets: [
                            'babel-preset-es2015',
                            'babel-preset-react'
                        ].map(require.resolve)
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Допиши описание что именно ты поменял и почему начало работать